# Unable to resolve setOnSeekBarChangeListener()

Tags: android, seekbar, android-seekbar

I'm doing some tests to simply change text color based off of three sliders as my RGB values in the main activity. The problem lies in being unable to set my custom listener on my sliders. Here's my code. Also, everything that needs to be is imported, just didn't include them because the code insertion thing on here doesn't like it;

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
int[] currentCol = {0, 0, 0};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


}
SeekBar Red = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.R);
SeekBar Blue = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.B);
SeekBar Green = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.G);

TextView textBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.colorText);


OnSeekBarChangeListener customListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar name, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        if (name == Red) {
            currentCol[0] = progress;
        } else if (name == Blue) {
            currentCol[1] = progress;
        } else if (name == Green) {
            currentCol[2] = progress;
        }
        textBox.setTextColor(Color.rgb(currentCol[0], currentCol[1], currentCol[2]));
    }


    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

};

public void setCustomListener(OnSeekBarChangeListener customListener) {
    this.customListener = customListener;
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first add  `implements OnSeekBarChangeListener{`

> public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
>   OnSeekBarChangeListener{

Call this in **oncreate()** function

```
SeekBar Red = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.R);
SeekBar Blue = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.B);
SeekBar Green = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.G);

Red.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); // set seekbar listener.
```

For practice Demo

1. [Android SeekBar Example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/widget/seekbar/android-seekbar-example/)

Comment: Oh. Putting it in the oncreate() function worked. I saw that link earlier too, but didn't realize that putting it there was required. I feel dumb for not paying that much attention now. Thanks!

Comment: @IntoxicatedPenguin Sometimes it happens .Be cool .Move ahead